# Syntax for an onChange event

Tags: javascript, onchange, acrobat

I have an Adobe Acrobat form and I use a small java script to obscure certain areas of the form based on selections in other fields.

```
if (event.value = "No") {
event.target.fillColor = color.white ;
} else {
event.target.fillColor = color.transparent ;
}
```

This works ok for me the first time I make a selection but once I select "No" for the first time it doesn't matter if I go in and change my selection, the backgrounds stay white.
I've been told I need to add an onChange event but I have no idea where to start.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: please show us your full code

Comment: `=` does assignment, which is not a syntax error in an `if` condition but is (usually) a logic error. `===` or `==` do comparison.

Comment: ^ This is the reason for your problem. Also, did you use "*a small java script*", or a small JavaScript script? ;)

Comment: Thanks nnnnnn that seems to have done the trick. Thank you all for your quick responses.

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, `=` **assigns** to a value, and `==` **compares against** that value, without assigning.

Let's look at the following code:

```
if (event.value = "No") { }
```

It works the first time because it **assigns** `event.value` to `No` (regardless of what it was before), and the assignment is successful, so the condition evaluates to `true`.

It then subsequently succeeds every time for the same reason.

To fix this, you're looking for `if (event.value == "No") { }`, or the stricter `if (event.value === "No") { }`, which also checks that `event.value` matches the **type** of `No`.

`===` is really important when dealing with numbers, because in JavaScript, a string representation of `1` is not the same thing as an integer representation of `1`:

```js
console.log("1" == 1);
console.log("1" === 1);
console.log("1" + 1);
console.log(1 + 1);
```

Hope this helps! :)